# appengine import_transform custom value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

From what I could figure out, it is not very easy to assign default values to properties in the bulkloader.yaml file. I learned that one way to set default values is to write your own function:

```
 - property: status
      external_name: status
      import_transform: extrabulkloadfunctions.staticvalue(int)
```

So I modified the transform.none_if_empty(int) function so that it returns the string 'in queue' instead of None.

```
def staticvalue(fn):

  def wrapper(value):
    if value == '' or value is None:
      return 'in queue'
    return fn(value)

  return wrapper
```

I was wondering though, since input_transform only accepts a function, whether it would be possible to pass in a default value so that I don't have to write a new function for every single kind of default value I want to pass in. I.E:

```
import_transform: extrabulkloadfunctions.staticvalue("default A")
import_transform: extrabulkloadfunctions.staticvalue("default B")
```

etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import_transform: "lambda x: 'default A'"
```